# dkim fails in gmail with message-id issue

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, dkim

We have updated our Message-ID recently.  Since the update we noticed our DKIM started to fail and we are receiving the following message for the Message-ID format

Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bulten@e.mailsend.com designates 55.55.55.55 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@e.mailsend.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=bulten@e.mailsend.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mykey; d=e.mailsend.com;
 h=Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-to:To:Subject:Mime-Version:Content-Type:List-Unsubscribe; i=info@e.mailsend.com;

Message-ID: <51dd4e23.26413c0a.2b38.441dSMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com>

Our Message-ID are updated on the mail server level and this message is send to PMTA which adds the DKIM to send the email out.

** Domains and IPs are modified for security purposes.

Thank you inadvance.